# Transpose multiple rows of data in panda df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below table which shows rainfall by month in the UK across a number of years. I want to transpose it so that each row is one month/year and the data is chronological.

```
Year    JAN     FEB     MAR     APR
2010    79.7    74.8    79.4    48
2011    102.8   114.5   49.7    36.7
2012    110.9   60  37  128
2013    110.5   59.8    64.6    63.6
```

I would like it so the table looks like the below with year, month & rainfall as the columns:

```
2010    JAN 79.7
2010    FEB 74.8
2010    MAR 79.4
2010    APR 48
2011    JAN 102.8
2011    FEB 114.5
```

I think I need to use a for loop and iterate through each row to create a new dataframe but I'm not sure of the syntax. I've tried the below loop which nearly does what I want but doesn't output as a dataframe.

```
for index, row in weather.iterrows():
    print(row["Year"],row)

2014.0 Year    2014.0
JAN      188.0
FEB      169.2
MAR       80.0
APR       67.8
MAY       99.6
JUN       54.8
JUL       64.7
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you definitely don't want a `for` loop. You should always consider that as a last resort with pandas. This is a "wide-to-long" issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `for-loops` and instead use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

```
df.set_index('Year') \
  .stack() \
  .reset_index() \
  .rename(columns={'level_1': 'Month', 0: 'Amount'})

    Year Month  Amount
0   2010   JAN    79.7
1   2010   FEB    74.8
2   2010   MAR    79.4
3   2010   APR    48.0
4   2011   JAN   102.8
5   2011   FEB   114.5
6   2011   MAR    49.7
7   2011   APR    36.7
8   2012   JAN   110.9
9   2012   FEB    60.0
etc...
```

Comment: or `df.melt('Year',var_name='Month',value_name='Amount').sort_values('Year')` :)